# NullPointerException when Sending SMS

Tags: android, sms, nullpointerexception

When I send the SMS I am getting `NullPointerException`. I think may be issue in `context`. I am using this in `TabActivityGroup`.

This is my code:

```
   if(sendSMS.equals("1")) {
    double invoiceVal = getInvoiceValue();
    String phone = getPhoneNo(); 
    String[] arrPhone = phone.split(";");
    System.out.println("==arrPhone==" +arrPhone.length);
    StringBuffer sms = new StringBuffer();
    sms.append("Miscellaneous Sale");
    sms.append("\n");
    sms.append("\n");
    sms.append("Territory: " + territoryCode +"\n");
    sms.append("Sales Rep: " + strExecutive +"\n");
    sms.append("Route Code: " + routeCode +"\n");
    sms.append("Retailer Code: " + retailCode +" " +retailerName +"\n");
    sms.append("Invoice No: " + printInPrefix+"\\"+printInvoiceNo +"\n");
    sms.append("Invoice Value: " + df.format(invoiceVal) +"\n");
    sendSMS(arrPhone, sms.toString());
}



 String sendSMS(String[] arrPhone, String message){        
     String SENT = "SMS_SENT";
     smsStatus ="YES";
     String DELIVERED = "SMS_DELIVERED";
     String phoneNumber = "";
     try {
         for (int i = 0; i < arrPhone.length; i++) {
             phoneNumber = arrPhone[i];
             System.out.println("==phoneNumber==" +phoneNumber);
             PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(), 0, new Intent(SENT), 0);
             PendingIntent deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(), 0,new Intent(DELIVERED), 0);
             registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){
                @Override
                 public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
                     switch (getResultCode()){
                        case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS sent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            break;
                        case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Generic failure", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            smsStatus ="NO";
                            break;
                        case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No service",  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            smsStatus ="NO";
                            break;
                        case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Null PDU", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            smsStatus ="NO";
                            break;
                        case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Radio off", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            smsStatus ="NO"; 
                            break;
                      }
                }
             }, new IntentFilter(SENT));

              //---when the SMS has been delivered---
              registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){
                  @Override
                   public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
                        switch (getResultCode()){
                            case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS delivered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                break;
                            case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS not delivered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                smsStatus ="NO";
                                break;                        
                        }
                    }
                }, new IntentFilter(DELIVERED));        

                SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
                sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, sentPI, deliveredPI);       
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        smsStatus ="NO";
    }
     return smsStatus;

}
```

---

**Error:**

```
     06-21 15:46:31.335: W/System.err(7510): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-21 15:46:31.345: W/System.err(7510):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.registerReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:349)
06-21 15:46:31.345: W/System.err(7510):     at xont.ventura.controller.sales.LineDiscountActivity.sendSMS(LineDiscountActivity.java:1498)
06-21 15:46:31.345: W/System.err(7510):     at xont.ventura.controller.sales.LineDiscountActivity.saveInvoice(LineDiscountActivity.java:1354)
06-21 15:46:31.345: W/System.err(7510):     at xont.ventura.controller.sales.BatchActivity$2$1.onClick(BatchActivity.java:164)
06-21 15:46:31.345: W/System.err(7510):     at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:193)
06-21 15:46:31.345: W/System.err(7510):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:130)
06-21 15:46:31.355: W/System.err(7510):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
06-21 15:46:31.355: W/System.err(7510):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4668)
06-21 15:46:31.355: W/System.err(7510):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-21 15:46:31.355: W/System.err(7510):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:552)
06-21 15:46:31.355: W/System.err(7510):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:917)
06-21 15:46:31.355: W/System.err(7510):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:674)
06-21 15:46:31.355: W/System.err(7510):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I have tried using `SalesActivityGroup.group.getApplicationContext()` , `SalesActivityGroup.group.getParent()` , But till I'm getting same error.

`NullPointerException` line no `1498` place is:  registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){

Please tell me what is an issue in my code?

Comment: @Pairaba  see line 1498 of your LineDiscountActivity.java.something is null in this line

Comment: Try replacing getBaseContext() with just getApplicationContext()

Comment: Have you tried debugging your code and see what element is null?!

Comment: This line is saying '  registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){' NULL

Comment: `if(sendSMS.equals("1"))` and then `sendSMS(arrPhone, sms.toString())` ... i dont get that ... once `sendSMS` is string and another time is methode ?

Comment: One is variable, other one is method

Comment: It will compile. It calling that sendSMS() method but problem with `registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver()`

Comment: problem with this question is that you're not telling us whole story ... you just calling sendSMS() method of `LineDiscountActivity` from onClick in `BatchActivity` how instance of `LineDiscountActivity` is created ? using `new LineDiscountActivity()`?

Comment: SaveInvoice() & sendSMS() method is available in `LineDiscountActivity()` .After processing `BatchDiscount from BatchActivity ` it need to call `new LineDiscountActivity().saveInvoice()` after save invoice need to send the SMS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace `getBaseContext()` with `arg0`

You have errors here.

`onReceive` gives you context in `onReceive`.Then you should not use `getBaseContext()`

```
public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {   <--- Use this context i.e arg0
                     switch (getResultCode()){
                        case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS sent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            break;
```

Comment: I am getting error this place `registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){`. Anyhow acccroding to your suggestion i did & also tried comment `Toast` message, eventhough It through same error.

Comment: did you commented all toast messages and checked?

Comment: @VipulShah lol, lol, this code was taken from your answer ... which is wrong http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10869933/android-determining-why-sms-sending-failed :)

Comment: @SelvinLOL I cant stop laughing  :D.May be she has issue somewhere else I had used that method in current Activity class.She might be using it in Some other activity

Comment: Yes. I commented all `Toast` message.even though i am getting same error

Comment: Code is working normal activity. When I use in `TabActivityGroup` i am facing this issue

Comment: @SelvinThats the issue she is using TabActivityGroup

Comment: @VipulShah fix your old answer ... and yeah, i think the same (that she is calling sendSMS from second Activity )

Answer (score 1):

I think you `should use arg0 (which is Context )  instead of getBaseContext()` inside onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) in toast......

also change the getBaseContext in

```
PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(), 0
```

with `<your_actvity_name>.this`

Comment: I am getting error this place `registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){`. Anyhow acccroding to your suggestion i did & also tried comment `Toast` message, eventhough It through same error.

Answer (score 1):

since you're using ActivityGroup use this answer [How to get child activity in activity group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6391843/how-to-get-child-activity-in-activity-group) to get instance of `LineDiscountActivity` instead calling  `new LineDiscountActivity()` at `onClick` in `BatchActivity` class

You should never use "new" to create instance of class derived from Activity because such instance is not initiate properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try to start your receiver in your `onStart()`

```
private SMSReceiver smsReceiver;
@Override
public void onStart()
{
    super.onStart();

       smsReceiver = new SMSReceiver();
       IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
       intentFilter.addAction(SENT);
       registerReceiver(smsReceiver, intentFilter);

       //Start our own service
       Intent intent = new Intent(Activity.this, 
       SMSReceiver.class);
       startService(intent);   
 }
```

Receive it in a seperate class

```
private class SMSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
    {

            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
                switch (getResultCode())
                {
                    case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS sent", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
                        break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Invalid PhoneNumber", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No service", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Null PDU", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Radio off", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break; 
                } 
            }  
    }
```

Dont forget to unregister receiver in onStop()

```
  @Override
      protected void onStop() {
         super.onStop();
         unregisterReceiver(smsReceiver);  
     }
```

It working perfectly for me.I hope it will help you.